# XML: Xpath to read only the first level of Items without knowing the other levels

Tags: xml, xpath

my xml looks like:

```
<item>
  <item>
  </item>
</item>
<item>
  <item>
  </item>
  <item>
  </item>
</item>
<item>
  <item>
  </item>
  <item>
  </item>
</item>
```

So in fact I have x level down of the same node as I have on every other node above... 
How is the xpath to only get the first level of nodes here?

Comment: what do you mean *exactly* by 'first level' here? the outer-most items or the inner-most ones?

Comment: @ReneKoch are you sure that you receive the correct answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try the following:

```
//item/*[1]
```

**brief explanation**: this expression returns the first element under every node named `item`